# Using "of" or "out of" big confusion

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs, spoken-english

I'm really confused which one to use?

1- **Don't make a big deal out of it**

2- **Don't make a big deal of it**

The second part : are the following sentence makes sense in terms of meaning and using the proper preposition ?

1-I heard about the product but I haven't make a trade/business of/out of  it.

2- I am out of hope (means I ran out of hope )

3- you should take a screenshot of/out of  it.

Comment: Take your choice. The second is crisper!

Comment: @Ronald sole Tnx for the answer. I just added another part to the question can you give me your opinion please ??

Comment: So I think that all of the sentences in the question are fine except for the last. We cannot say "You should take a screenshot out of it." When we photograph something we take a photograph OF it, not a photograph OUT OF it.

Answer (score 1):

It is helpful if you change "it" to a noun phrase, e.g. "what I said"

In **Don't make a big deal out of what I said** - **out** is an adverb.

In "to **make** something **out** of something", "make out of" = to **create** something: **by using** something "He made a spear **out of/by using** a tree branch."

**Don't make a big deal out of what I said** = **Don't make a big deal by using what I said [in order to create that big deal]"**

2- **Don't make a big deal of what I said** "of" is best understood as "associated with". "Of" is not as precise as "out of" and the relationship between "a big deal "and "what I said" is understood from the context.

The difference is not important in your examples as the context tells us what is happening, but in other contexts, they are not the same:

"He made a fuss of the cat" (= he gave the cat a lot of loving attention) - He made a fuss *associated with* the cat.

But

"He made a fuss out of the cat" is wrong as it would mean that he made a fuss **by using** the cat [in some way].